# Lightning List View Cloning (restricting Sharing setting)

Tags: profile, sharing, list-view, tab, view

*I have found no reference that this is possible, so I'm hoping someone perhaps has some canned code or other reference material that would lead to a solution.*

This is in the Lightning experience, for reference.

- Admin creates some List Views for all users to use
- User wants to CLONE a List View on a custom object tab
- Admin/Dev wants to limit to them to ONLY saving it as "**Only I can see this list view**"

[image: Cloning list view screenshot]

Any solutions?  I do not see this as a Profile-controllable item.  Am I missing something simple (hopefully)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the users have Manage Public List Views, they can save list views that everyone can see. Remove this permission, and they'll get a UI that looks like this:

[image: Private List Only]

Note that the bottom option is greyed out, and the help text reads:

> You don't have permission to share this list.

You'll also probably want to read [Create or Clone a List View in Lightning Experience](http://Create%20or%20Clone%20a%20List%20View%20in%20Lightning%20Experience):

> **To create list views**: Read on the type of record included in the list AND Create and Customize List Views
>
> **To create, edit, or delete public list views**: Manage Public List Views

Comment: You're telling me it is NOT different with Lightning, essentially.  This is good news.  I already counseled them on "clone and alter".  I typically am NOT by my role now to be the one to "go in and test myself", but now did, and this is fine.  I need to sell it down the line (that they can NOT filter on the Public items WITHOUT cloning them first).   Thanks.